# Layer Definition for previous 30 days (JSON)

Tags: arcgis-online, json

I am writing a JSON query into my layer definition of a web map on ArcGIS Online to only show features that were edited in the past 30 days using current timestamp.
What I'm using now (seen below) is not working. No errors are given but it simply hides all features even if features were in fact edited within the 30 day range

```
"layerDefinition": {
    "definitionExpression": "last_edited_date BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

  },
```

Any ideas how to correct this code?

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: This is a AGOL Web map, sorry I will update OP